# Sending http request inside django's asynchttpconsumer?

Tags: django

I have an asynchttpconsumer class in my django project that receives webhooks from an external server. during the webhook request, I would like the to send a http request to an authorization server, get the response back, and use that to finish processing the webhook request. I followed this tutorial but extended the code that I have. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#asynchttpconsumer

```
class frontEndConsumer(AsyncHttpConsumer):
    async def http_request(self, request):
        header = self.scope
        print(header)
        # connect to auth server
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("https://******.auth0.com", 80)
        headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer *******************" }
        print("request get connection")
        conn.request("GET", "/userinfo", headers=headers)

        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        # do some processing
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))  
        # do other stuff

        await self.http_reply(data)
        return
```

Since I am using an authentication service (auth0), I used their example for getting information back from here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/02-using
but I keep getting errno -2 on the "conn.request" line:

```
Exception inside application: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
  File "/home/jeremy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "/home/jeremy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "/home/jeremy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "/home/jeremy/Documents/APbackend/myapp/webhook.py", line 59, in http_request
    conn.request("GET", "/userinfo", headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1264, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1310, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1259, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 948, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
  [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I cannot find any references to this error or or if this is even the right approach to what I'm trying to do!

Comment: You should probably use something like aiohttp

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what happened:

my URL should be without https://

I get a 301 error after this

this was caused by HTTPConnection, auth0 doesn't support http, only https. so it needs to change to HTTPSConnection and port to 443.

was able to get it to work after that.